# android market: "Got auth failure from server -> invalidating auth tokens"

Tags: android

anybody know how to resolve this issue? I have an older device (Google I/O phone) and I've discovered that I can't install or upgrade any apps, no matter what I do.

I've tried rebooting, clearing all caches, deleting apps to save memory, installing a SIM card, removing the SIM card, and everything else.

When I run logcat, I see this message whenever I try to install an app:

```
com.android.vending.AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got auth failure from server -> invalidating auth tokens.
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Update:  Also seeing this on a Samsung Moment, also running 1.5.  Is it possible that the Android Market has stopped supported 1.5?

Another update; factory reset seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Is your Google account username and password correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure; I was able to get email, etc.  I also logged into Google Talk (a good way to refresh your credentials).

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, be sure to post your answer and accept it.

Comment: Heh. Well, it really isn't a solution.  What if I wanted to install software *without* doing a factory reset?  I suppose what I really ought to do is file a bug report, but now that I've done the reset, I can't reproduce the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same issue with my good old T-Mobile G1 (Android 1.6). I tried clearing all kinds of caches and syncing data and using Google Talk and whatnot. **What finally solved it was to uninstall the Android Market app updates.** Then I just had to sign in again (using an app specific Google Account password) and the downloading of apps worked.